# Where to get master list of mutual funds?

Tags: mutual-fund, ftp, edgar

I cant seem to find a straight answer anywhere on Google for this.  I would like to create a master list of all known mutual funds and their ticker symbol.

Is it possible to get this data from Edgar's FTP?  Is there a particular form that registered investment companies have to file that would have this information that I could crawl the Edgar index for?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  One more quick question, if I crawled the Edgar FTP for all form N-Qs and then took a distinct list off all of the Series/Contracts, what would that give me?  Sorry for the ignorance, this is definitely not my field of expertise.  Is a Series/Contract with a Ticker symbol a mutual fund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little chance that you find a single database that holds **all** the mutual funds in the world, especially for free.

Some companies made a business out of this, such as [Morningstar](http://www.morningstar.com/). They will also provide you with the prospectus, historical data when available, and other useful information. But obviously you'll have to pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using `Yahoo Finance` then you can download this spreadsheet which currently contains approximately `4919 Mutual Funds` & their `Tickers`. hope it helps:

http://investexcel.net/all-yahoo-finance-stock-tickers/